# Which hdX,Y do I use when trying to repair grub rescue without live cd/usb?

Tags: ubuntu, grub, partition-recovery, boot-partition

I deleted my linux mint partition not knowing that it would cause me to be unable to acess ubuntu, i have found another artial on how to fix it without a live cd/usb but i dont know what hdX,Y to use. pleas help, i have 1 320gb hybrid drive on a lenovo N585m

Answer (score 2):

No one can know that, apart from you. But there is, of course, a way to find out, with these commands:

```
  ls                               # List the known drives (hdX) and partitions (hdX,Y)
  ls (hdX,Y)/                      # List the contents of the partition's root
  ls (hdX,Y)/boot/grub             # Normal location of the Grub 2 modules.
  ls (hdX,Y)/usr/lib/grub/i386-pc  # Alternate location of the Grub 2 modules.
```

ls (hdX,Y)/boot/grub should show a lot of .mod files. If it does, this is the directory you are searching for, otherwise try the alternate location I suggested above. This identifies the values of (X,Y) you need. An error

```
  "error: unknown filesystem"
```

simply means this is not your Ubuntu partition.